# PDO connect to Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I'm trying connect to Oracle.
This is my code:

```
$dsn="oci:dbname=//oracleserver:1521/xe;charset=AL32UTF8";
$user="portal2";
$password="portal2";
try{
    $arrConnectOptions  = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true);
    $arrConnectOptions += array(PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_UPPER);
    $arrConnectOptions += array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $arrConnectOptions += array(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING);
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $arrConnectOptions);
    $sql = "select count(*) from tbl_message";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
        var_dump($row);
    }
    unset($dbh);
    echo "OK";
}catch (PDOException $e){
    print("Error:".$e->getMessage());
    echo "NG";
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 NG");
    die();
}catch (Exception $ex){
    print("Error: ".$ex->getMessage());
}

$dbh = null;
```

When I execute on Linux command line: php check.php, It's ok
But when I try to open on web browser. I got error message
"Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

P/S: Server is running. (Centos 7)

Please help me

Comment: Thanks Fred, We only use "." with string, About the array additions, we need to use "+" - http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

Comment: What happens if you dont send the `500` header?

Comment: I fixed: Sometime, Sometime Oracle not connected on web browser
I run this code on my server and It's running:
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on

Answer (score 2):

Do you have dispaly_errors set to 1 and error_reporting set to E_ALL? My best guess is that since it is common for PHP CLI and the web server to use different PHP.ini files, you have the OCI driver enabled in the CLI ini and not in the web server ini. If you web server ini isn't set to display the errors you could get the error above.

Comment: Thanks Aronkerr, I used your suggestion but I still get this error, no more information. I checked my configuration with phpinfo(), and I see OCI driver was enabled on Web browser. Have you any more idea for it?

Comment: Using the same code you have above and switching it out to hit my local oracle db works fine. You must have something present in your config for CLI that isn't present in the other. Do you have the error display enabled?

Comment: I fixed: Sometime Oracle not connected on web browser
I run this code on my server and It's running:
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on